# check length of string start with 0?

Tags: javascript

I am working with the following code and I want to perform a length check of `valueofzip`. When I set `valueofzip = 08820` I want this to not come under the following condition, mean to say it goes to `else` block. How can I perform it?

```
var valueofzip = 08820;
if (isNaN(valueofzip) || valueofzip.toString().length < 5 || || valueofzip > 99999) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showClientError("Entered Zipcode is invalid, Please input a valid 5 digit number");
    $('#zip').addClass("input-validation-error");
    isvalid = false;
}
else
{
    alert("valid");
}
```

Comment: There is also a double `||` in your if conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your zip code as a string, not a numerical value. Then use a simple regular expression to test that you have exactly five digits:

```
var valueofzip = "08820";
var pattern = /^\d{5}$/;
if (pattern.test(valueofzip)) {
    alert("valid");
} else {
    . . .
}
```

A big problem with using numbers you discovered: a leading zero doesn't do what you want. At best it gets lost. At the worst, it is interpreted as an octal literal (now deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax error**: there is a duplicated || between "<5" and ">99999".

It will not go to else statement since the valueofzip.toString().length equals 4.

You can see that easily in console (most common browser provide Developer tools to help you debugging the code,  press F12 to launch it).

Answer (score 0):

Your `valueofzip` variable will not be `08820`, its a int, a number, it will strip away the first 0, cause numbers don't start with 0 like that.. `valueofzip` is actually `8820`. Treat it like a string all the way through.

Instead of isNan, check so that the var only contains numbers, this can be done with a simple regex like: `/^\d+$/.test(valueofzip)`.
This way, you will know that the string is only numbers, and the length will stay as it should, 5 characters long.
If you wish to keep it within the range `00000 => 99999`, just check so that the length is ONLY 5 chars: `valueofzip.length === 5`

Also, remove the duplicate || in the if-clause, it will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the starting zeros and check for the condition, here is the code

```
var retStr = '';      
function removeStartingZeros( str ){    
   if( str.indexOf(0) == '0' ){     
      str = str.replace(0,'').trim();    
      removeStartingZeros( str );   
   }     
   else retStr=str;     
   return retStr;        
}      
var valueofzip = "000000000000000008820";             
valueofzip  = removeStartingZeros( '000000000000000008820' );    
// here 'valueofzip' will be equal to '8820'
if( /^\d+$/.test(valueofzip)  && valueofzip.length > 4){    
    // your code for ...if valid string      
}
else{
   // your code for....if invalid string
}
```